# Mocha prematurely exits from testing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) to run some tests on my [SnailMailAddressParser](http://brianmhunt.github.com/SnailMailAddressParser/) project from the command-line. Unfortunately only some tests are run before Mocha exits.

The test file is very straightforward. You can [see the test file here: test/test.coffee](https://github.com/brianmhunt/SnailMailAddressParser/blob/master/test/test.coffee)

It seems there is a race condition somewhere. When I run `npm test`, it does one of two things:

1. Runs [one test](https://github.com/brianmhunt/SnailMailAddressParser/blob/master/test/test.coffee#L13); or
2. Runs 34 tests, starting at [address_tester](https://github.com/brianmhunt/SnailMailAddressParser/blob/master/test/test.coffee#L55).

Clearly I am doing something asynchronous that needs to be caught, but I am not quite sure what yet. In any case, I do not know how to tell Mocha to wait for any asynchronous items to be reaped (i.e. some sort of `Mocha.wait_all`, if that is even possible - perhaps I have to add' `done()` calls, but I didn't think that was necessary for synchronous testing - which I thought this might be).

I will experiment of course and post any answers I glean from my testing, but I would be grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that

```
 fs.readFile filename, "utf8", -> ...
```

was operating asynchronously. When I had tried using

```
 fs.readFileSync filename, "utf8", -> ...
```

it was not working because I was still passing a callback instead of reading the return value.

I solved the problem by changing the callback to:

```
data = fs.readFileSync filename, "utf8"
```

as no asynchronous operation was now being called.